# Clutch pedal is sticking and will not go down all the way on a 1994 nissan frontier truck

Tags: clutch, nissan, manual-transmission, frontier

The clutch pedal on my 1994 Nissan Frontier will only go down about one quarter of the entire throw. I can put the shifter in gear but its like I still have the clutch pushed in.  I can shift into any gear without touching the clutch.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  What is your question?  You can use the edit button below your question to edit it and additional information.  Anything else you can add will be helpful.  Cheers!

Comment: Does the pedal only travel the first 1/4 or last 1/4 of it's travel, to put another way, does the pedal return to the top of the stroke when you release it or is it stuck at the bottom?

Comment: The clutch is sticking at the top of the stroke. when I push down on the clutch pedal it feels like i'm pushing on the brake.

Comment: I can shift the gears without touching the clutch.It's as if the clutch stays in, and the truck will not move.